# Changes committed in one transaction are not available in parallel transaction in H2 database

Tags: java, sql, database, transactions, h2

I try to implement transfer between two accounts, so that it works correctly in concurrent transactions. But for some reason the second transaction is waiting until the first one makes all updates, but it doesn't see changes made it. As a result, balances are not updated correctly.

1. Is it behaviour correct or not?
2. If it is correct, then why? [H2 docs](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#mvcc) explicitly say that changes made by commit transaction become visible for other transactions.
3. If this approach to make transfers is basically wrong, which one is correct? But please, bare in mind, that I would like to rely on database facilities, not Java locks, etc.

**H2 database settings**

- version 1.4.196
- MVCC engine is turned on: `MVCC mode is enabled by default in version 1.4.x`
- Transactions isolation levels are ignored: `If MVCC is enabled, changing the lock mode (LOCK_MODE) has no effect)`
- Multithreading mode is turned on: `MULTI_THREADED=1`

**Test case**

- Initial balances:

  1. `acc1` = `300`
  2. `acc2` = `400`
- Make two parallel transfers (the second one is delayed for 200ms):

  1. `50` from `acc1` to `acc2`
  2. `200` from `acc2` to `acc1`
- Expected final balance:

  1. `acc1` = `450` (minus `50`, plus `200`)
  2. `acc2` = `250` (plus `50`, minus `200`)
- Actual final balances:

  1. `acc1` = `500`
  2. `acc2` = `200`

**SQL Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (
  ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NUMBER VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  BALANCE DECIMAL(19,2) DEFAULT 0 CHECK (BALANCE >= 0)
);

INSERT INTO ACCOUNT(NUMBER, BALANCE) VALUES('acc1', 300);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT(NUMBER, BALANCE) VALUES('acc2', 400);
```

**Unit test**

```
public class ConcurrentTransfersTest {
    @Test
    void testForStackOverflow() throws Exception {
        final String url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MULTI_THREADED=1;" +
                "INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/h2/schema.sql'\\;RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/h2/test-data.sql'";

        JdbcConnectionPool pool = JdbcConnectionPool.create(url, "sa", "");

        assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(30000, 2), readData(pool, 1));
        assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(40000, 2), readData(pool, 2));

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> updateData("t1", pool, 1, 2, BigDecimal.valueOf(50)));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> updateData("t2", pool, 2, 1, BigDecimal.valueOf(200)));

        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(200);
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(40000, 2), readData(pool, 1));
        assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(30000, 2), readData(pool, 2));

        try (Connection c = pool.getConnection(); Statement st = c.createStatement()) {
            st.execute("SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATELY");
        }
    }

    private BigDecimal readData(DataSource ds, long id) {
        try (Connection c = ds.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement select = c.prepareStatement("SELECT BALANCE FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ID = ?")) {
            return readFromPreparedStatment(select, id);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private BigDecimal readFromPreparedStatment(PreparedStatement select, long id) throws Exception {
        select.setLong(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        BigDecimal b = rs.getBigDecimal(1);
        rs.close();

        return b;
    }

    private void updateData(String thread, DataSource ds, long from, long to, BigDecimal amount) {
        try {
            try (Connection c = ds.getConnection();
                 PreparedStatement minus = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE ACCOUNT SET BALANCE = BALANCE - ? WHERE ID = ?");
                 PreparedStatement plus = c.prepareStatement("UPDATE ACCOUNT SET BALANCE = BALANCE + ? WHERE ID = ?");
                 PreparedStatement select = c.prepareStatement("SELECT BALANCE FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ID = ?")
            ) {
                c.setAutoCommit(false);

                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + thread + ": transfer " + amount + " " +
                                "from = " + readFromPreparedStatment(select, from) + " to = " + readFromPreparedStatment(select, to));

                minus.setBigDecimal(1, amount);
                minus.setLong(2, from);
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + thread + ": from minus " + amount);
                minus.executeUpdate();

                Thread.sleep(2000);

                plus.setBigDecimal(1, amount);
                plus.setLong(2, to);
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + thread + ": to plus " + amount);
                plus.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + thread + ": from = " + readFromPreparedStatment(select, from));
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + thread + ": to = " + readFromPreparedStatment(select, to));

                c.commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1508149269895 t1: transfer 50 from = 300.00 to = 400.00
1508149269895 t1: from minus 50
1508149271899 t1: to plus 50
1508149271900 t1: before commit from = 250.00
1508149271900 t1: before commit to = 450.00
1508149271913 t2: transfer 200 from = 400.00 to = 300.00
1508149271913 t2: from minus 200
1508149273918 t2: to plus 200
1508149273918 t2: before commit from = 200.00
1508149273918 t2: before commit to = 500.00
```

Comment: The H2 docs you linked to also states **The following applies when using the PageStore storage engine: The MVCC feature is not fully tested yet. The limitations of the MVCC mode are: with the PageStore storage engine, it can not be used at the same time as MULTI_THREADED=TRUE;**

Comment: As far as I can see, MVStore is a default engine in H2 since version 1.4. PageStore was default in 1.3.

Comment: Posted [an issue in h2databse tracker](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/642)